# jsf resource database without xml

Tags: database, postgresql, jsf, annotations, resources

i am trying to make a web application using jsf technology.
I don't know java ee yet and got a little confused with all the versions and frameworks. 
I want to add a database to the application (postgresql),
I understand that it should be persistence and available to the app always so i am trying to sign it in JNDI and let the other classes get it from there, this is what i have done, I don't know if it is the way to do it and how to get access to it from other classess:

```
import shay.eilon.zolbareshet.logging.Logger;
import shay.eilon.zolbareshet.logging.LoggerFactory;


import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
@PersistenceUnit
public class DataBase {
    @Resource(name = "zolDB")
    private javax.sql.DataSource myDB;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
    private final static int LOGIN_TIME_OUT = 20;


    public Connection getC() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setC(Connection c) {
        this.connection = c;
    }

    public DataBase() {
        myDB = new ZolDataSource();
        try {
            connection= myDB.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




        private class ZolDataSource implements DataSource {
            private Connection connection = null;

            public ZolDataSource() {
                try {
                    connection = DriverManager
                            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Zol",
                                    "postgres", "password");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
                return connection;
            }

            @Override
            public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
                Connection c = null;
                try {
                    c = DriverManager
                            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Zol",
                                    username, password);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return c;
            }

            @Override
            public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
                PrintWriter p = null;
                try {
                    p = new PrintWriter(logger.getLogFile());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return p;
            }

            @Override
            public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter out) throws SQLException {

            }

            @Override
            public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {

            }

            @Override
            public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
                return LOGIN_TIME_OUT;
            }

            @Override
            public java.util.logging.Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException {
                return false;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: To start, are you targeting a real Java EE server or a barebones Servletcontainer? Approaches are quite different on those. Your current class contains a mix of them which indeed doesn't make sense.

Comment: I started to work with tomcat but has some problems so I think I will work with glassfish,
I wrote some bean classes and managed to write jsf - xhtml page that contain h:form and work with one of those beans, but I don't understand how to make the database part of the application.

Comment: In that case, read on JPA (for Java EE), not JDBC (for Tomcat). After all, this isn't a JSF problem.

Comment: if it possible I want to be able to get the database configuration (port, user, password) from a configuration file and not to use one of the xml files or hard coded it